# How to print the void * in a function and how to access the void * variable in a function?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, compiler-errors, void-pointers

I'm trying to pass a function as argument to another function with `void` pointer and it doesn't work

```
#include "header.h"
void print ( void *Arg )
{
//  while ( ( int *) Arg[0] )
    {
        printf ( "Arg[0] = %d Arg[1] = %d\n",(int *)  Arg[0], (int * ) Arg[1] );
        sleep ( 1 );
        //Arg[0]--;
        //Arg[1]--;
    }
}
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int count[2] = { 10, 160};
    print (count);
}
```

I Am getting errors like this:

```
void*.c: In function ‘print’:
void*.c:6:52: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
   printf ( "Arg[0] = %d Arg[1] = %d\n",(int *)  Arg[0], (int * ) Arg[1] );
                                                    ^
void*.c:6:3: error: invalid use of void expression
   printf ( "Arg[0] = %d Arg[1] = %d\n",(int *)  Arg[0], (int * ) Arg[1] );
   ^
void*.c:6:69: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
   printf ( "Arg[0] = %d Arg[1] = %d\n",(int *)  Arg[0], (int * ) Arg[1] );
                                                                     ^
void*.c:6:3: error: invalid use of void expression
   printf ( "Arg[0] = %d Arg[1] = %d\n",(int *)  Arg[0], (int * ) Arg[1] );
```

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: You can't use a `void*` pointer to access an array, since it in not known what size each element is.

Comment: `void main()`--> `int main()`

Comment: Since the `print` function will only work when passed a pointer to `int`, I don't know why you make life difficult by casting to and from a `void*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a pointer you need the `"%p"` [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format.

But it seems that you don't actually want to print the actual pointer but what *it points to*, and this is where your error comes from, because your casting is in the wrong place, you need to cast the pointer before you dereference it, like e.g.

```
((int *) Arg)[0]
```

It's a problem with [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) where the array subscript operator has higher precedence than the type-cast operator. So the compiler thinks you are doing `(int *) (Arg[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

The array subscript operator (de-referencing) can be used with a complete type. `void *` is not a complete type that you can dereference.

To get this done, you need to `cast` the `Arg` itself to `int *` and then use the dereference operator to get the value.

Also, to print a pointer, you need to use `%p` format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this maybe

```
printf ( "Arg[0] = %d Arg[1] = %d\n",((int *)Arg)[0], ((int * )Arg)[1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that the subscript operator used in the printf as for example `Arg[0]` or `Arg[1]` is applied to a pointer of type `void *`.

You have at first to cast this pointer to type `int *` and only then to apply the subscript operator

```
void print ( void *Arg )
{
//  while ( ( int *) Arg[0] )
    {
        printf ( "Arg[0] = %d Arg[1] = %d\n", ( (int *)  Arg )[0], ( (int * ) Arg )[1] );
        sleep ( 1 );
        //Arg[0]--;
        //Arg[1]--;
    }
}
```

Or the code would be simpler if in the beginning of the function you would define a local pointer. For example

```
void print ( void *Arg )
{
    int *p = Arg;
//  while ( ( int *) Arg[0] )
    {
        printf ( "Arg[0] = %d Arg[1] = %d\n", p[0], p[1] );
        sleep ( 1 );
        //Arg[0]--;
        //Arg[1]--;
    }
}
```